# Computer acting weird

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate, standby

My specs:

```
Windows XP PRO SP3 with latest updates of course
Motherboard - Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3
CPU - DualCore Intel Core 2 Duo E4300, 1800 MHz (9 x 200)
Video card - Gigabyte GeForce 7200 GS
```

I have this strange problem with PC lately, my front panel display is acting strange(but it's other question, click me to see it), after hibernation computer doesn't turn off - restarts only, and when going to sleep computer wakes up.
I cleared CMOS and still no result. Im sure it's something with Windows XP and not something with hardware.

**Update**
I installed same version of Windows XP(from same CD) on other hard drive, and it works perfectly. Can I fix my current issue? Also my computer sometimes freezes when Windows completed laoding programs and stuff.

Comment: have you tried a different OS?

Comment: If you are sure its with Windows XP, then you have your answer, this is likely a compatability problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a second hard drive you can swap into the problem machine, do this:

Put the other HDD into the machine, removing your current one.
Install windows and update drivers and system patches.
Test for instability.

If the system still crashes or has these weird power management issues, or other instabilities, the problem is with your hardware (other than the hard drive).

If the computer works fine, the problem is with your old Windows install (or the other hard drive). Either way, you'll want to reinstall (clean, not repair) Windows on the old HDD. If the problems go away, it was the OS. If they persist, it's the HDD.

My experience tells me this is a hardware failure issue. Power management requires each of the system drivers to support the power state, if a device is failing or does not support a selected power state, the system will either not allow you to go into that power state, or may fail when you do.

Comment: No, it's something with Windows. Because it works perfectly on other HDD.

Comment: The other HDD installed in the SAME computer?

Comment: Yes! Same installation disk, same computer. Only other hard drive.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is OS as you've noted. So update all drivers with the latest from the vendor. If the problem doesn't go away it's probably time for a fresh install.

Comment: Well I haven't SMBUS Controller installed. But it wasn't installed all time. There no problems with drivers. I think I used hibernation too much. I don't shutdown computer at all. And yes, I think it's time for a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I left my LAN cable plugged in.
No kidding. Try plugging it out before sending it to sleep or before hibernating.

Works for me. :) (Though, there must be a setting for the LAN device, which causes the wake up.)

Comment: Shiki: Try updating your computer's drivers. Especially the network card and chipset. Your symptoms indicate that your network device does not correctly handle the Sleep power state.

Comment: Well, when I update my drivers on my laptop (where it happens more often), the laptop gets a BSOD. Quite often. The main PC got the same symptons, even though it's got a Realtek card. I tried the driver from the CD, from the Gigabyte site, and from the Realtek one. | I only get BSOD on my LAPTOP, with an Intel card. The PC _only_ wakes up/restarts.